# Question about R (manipulating model output)

Tags: discussion

I have [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315918/manipulating-results-of-summarymodel) about using R , which I already posted on stackoverflow, but then I realised it might be better to post here - though I'm not really sure where is best ? Should I ask to migrate it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That question seems to be in the best location already, because it asks about how to manipulate some R objects and does not appear to require any statistical expertise or thinking for an answer: that's the criterion we apply to decide where the best fit is.

If it does not get a satisfactory answer within a reasonable time--give it a day or two--then consider flagging it for migration here.  It might get a few votes to close--it's really in a gray area--but in the meantime it could also get a useful comment or reply.

Comment: Thank you. I've already got a great answer so I'm sorry to have been impatient asking about it here (better than cross-posting, though, right ?)